# Calling the .Any Extension Method with Entity Framework using Expression Trees

Tags: c#, entity-framework, expression-trees

I have looked at few examples here [Calling a Method from an Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439172/calling-a-method-from-an-expression) and on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx) but I have not been able to get the right method call/object type for Any() for the query below. I seem to be able to get the property call but not IEnumerable part of the child property.
billing_map_set_lu is the parent of billmaps_lu and is defined as an association in the Entity Framework.

The reason I am using expression trees is that 
I need to be able to define the query at runtime with 1-n .SelectMany(p => p.billmaps_lu).Where(predicate) clauses. So I figured if I could build the expression trees I could handle all the different combinations I have for this system which are many.

```
var myResults = ctx.billing_map_set_lu
                   .Where(p => p.billmaps_lu.Any(b => b.billmap_columnname == "templatesittings_key" &&  b.billmap_columnvalue == 428264))
                                   SelectMany(p => p.billmaps_lu)
                   .Where (b =>b.billmap_columnname =="locations_key" && b.billmap_columnvalue == 12445)
                                   Select(z => z.billing_map_set_lu);
```

I have tried a quite a few attempts using the samples above...

```
ParameterExpression bms = Expression.Parameter(typeof(billmaps_lu));
Expression left1 = Expression.Property(bms, typeof(billmaps_lu).GetProperty("billmap_columnname"));
Expression right1 = Expression.Constant("templatesittings_key", typeof(string));
Expression InsideAny1 = Expression.Equal(left1, right1);
Expression left2 = Expression.Property(bms, typeof(billmaps_lu).GetProperty("billmap_columnvalue"));
Expression right2 = Expression.Constant(428264, typeof(int));
Expression InsideAny2 = Expression.Equal(left2, right2);
Expression myWhereClause1 = Expression.AndAlso(InsideAny1, InsideAny2);
```

The above part seems fine but when I try to do the .Any It is like I can't get the right property/method to get the right objects out.  (I feel like I am on a physics problem where I am working with the wrong units.) I am hoping it is something simple that I am missing, I am pretty new to Expression Trees.. I have included non-working code to try to show you where my head is at and how someone can steer me in the right direction.

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name == "Any" && m.GetParameters().Length == 2).Single().MakeGenericMethod(typeof(billing_map_set_lu).GetProperty("billmaps_lu").PropertyType);
ParameterExpression billMapSetParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(billing_map_set_lu), "p");
ParameterExpression billMaps = Expression.Parameter(typeof(billmaps_lu), "p1");
var myFunction = Expression.Lambda<Func<billmaps_lu, bool>>(Expression.Call(method, Expression.Property(billMapSetParameter, typeof(billing_map_set_lu).GetProperty("billmaps_lu")), myWhereClause1), billMaps)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Disclaimer, I haven't got any compiled working code.*

2 problems.

First problem probably lies in:

```
ParameterExpression billMapSetParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(billing_map_set_lu), "p");
```

That's not a parameter you need in:

```
Expression.Lambda<Func<billmaps_lu, bool>>(Expression.Call(method, Expression.Property(**billMapSetParameter**, typeof(billing_map_set_lu).GetProperty("billmaps_lu")), myWhereClause1), billMaps)
```

Change the billMapSetParameter to the billMaps ParamterExpression, then you should be good to go. You are calling the PropertyExpression to obtain your billMapSet for you from the ParameterExpression.

2nd problem: (Not sure, but my gut feeling)
You may need to pass the Where clause as a ConstantExpression with type Expression<.Func<>>. .Any method takes two parameters, of which, the second is an Expression<.Func<>> (Or just a Func<>? can't remember).

```
var whereExpression = Expression.Lambda<.Func<.billmaps_lu, bool>>(myWhereClause1, bms);
var ce = Expression.Constant(whereExpression)
```

Then pass back ce into originally where you "myWhereClause1" is.

*Cross finger it works*

Edit- Scrap that, SHOW MI ZEH CODEZ

```
public class Foo
{
    public List<string> Strings { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Func<Foo, bool> func =
            a => a.Strings.Any(b => b == "asdf");

        // b => b == "asdf";
        var bParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof (string));
        var asdfConstant = Expression.Constant("asdf");
        var compare = Expression.Equal(bParameter, asdfConstant);
        var compareExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<string, bool>>(compare, bParameter);
        var ceCompareExpression = Expression.Constant(compareExpression.Compile());

        // a => a.Strings.Any(compareExpression)
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof (Foo));

        var foosProperty = Expression.Property(parameter, typeof (Foo).GetProperty("Strings"));
        MethodInfo method = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name == "Any" && m.GetParameters().Length == 2).Single().MakeGenericMethod(typeof(string));

        var anyMethod = Expression.Call(method, foosProperty, ceCompareExpression);

        var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Foo, bool>>(anyMethod, parameter);

        // Test.
        var foo = new Foo {Strings = new List<string> {"asdf", "fdsas"}};

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("original func result: {0}", func(foo)));
        Console.Write(string.Format("constructed func result: {0}", lambdaExpression.Compile()(foo)));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Sleeper Smith! I had pretty much given up on this one and did a work around not using the expression trees, but I will try your answer when we refactor the code, which is coming up so it is very timely that you answered now. Thanks again!